# Questions on Nebula NatTable sorting and filtering

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable, nebula

I have been using Nebula NatTable for quite sometime in my project and is familiar with the basics. I Have 2 questions on sorting and filtering.

1. There are separate examples given for sorting and filtering  [filter
   example](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_603_Filter/_6031_GlazedListsFilterExample.java), [sort example](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_600_GlazedLists/_602_GlazedListsSortingExample.java) . My question is , can I include both
   these features in one instance of NatTable?
2. Can I remove the filterheader control after the NatTable instance is
   created? If yes, how can that be done ?

Comment: Regarding your first question, it can certainly be done. See the  [Everything_but_the_kitchen_sink](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/examples/_900_Everything_but_the_kitchen_sink.java) example.

Comment: Thanks . I will check the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes and there are several examples showing that. Some of them are for example located in *Tutorial Examples - Integration*. All the features in NatTable can be combined.
2. I suppose you mean the filter header row, as there is no special control for it. It can not be removed in terms of removing it from the layer stack afterwards. But the visibility can be changed at runtime. There is even a key binding by default enabled to do that. By pressing F3 you can toggle the visibility at runtime. The question is, why do you want to remove the filter row after the creation time. Typically people are doing it for programmatically filtering, but that should be possible without the filter row by applying filters to the `FilterList`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the examples and was able to integrate with my application. And Yes I meant the filter row visibility(and not removal). F3 works like magic. Cool stuff!!