# Sorting and filtering in Nattable with Column Grouping

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, nattable

**Background:**

I have referred NatTable examples for integrating both sorting and filtering along with column grouping functionalities into a single table. It is not working as expected. If I try to add Sorting and filtering features individually it works like a charm but the integration of both with column grouping is not working. Based on the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626763/questions-on-nebula-nattable-sorting-and-filtering) I have tried to add the needed configurations to the nattable but still it doesn't work.

**Code Snippet :**

```
  /**
   * Sorting Layer
   */
  GridLayer gridLayer = new GridLayer(viewportLayer,columnGroupHeaderLayer, rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayer);
  /**
   * Since I am able to add only single grid layer to nat table
   */
  this.natTable = new NatTable(parent, gridLayer, false);
   /**
   * FilteringLayer
   */
  this.grid = new FilterableGridLayer(this.eventList, propertyNames, propertyToLabelMap, configRegistry);              
  this.natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
  this.natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
  this.natTable.addConfiguration(new FilterRowConfiguration());
  this.natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
  this.natTable.configure();
```

Is there is any way to add both the sort and filter grid layer along with the column grouping into a single nat table?

Comment: Yes this is working pretty well. There should be an example in the integration section of the NatTable examples application. As you are not explaining what isn't working, I can't help you in any way. I just can say that it works and I implemented this multiple times.

Comment: @Dirk Fauth : Thanks for the reply... 8 have gone through the example in the integration section , In that example filtering and grouping is working but sorting is not working. Tats the problem. I need to implement all these three in a single table.

Comment: The example is not containing the `SingleClickSortConfiguration`. So you need to press ALT when clicking a column header to trigger sorting.

Comment: @Dirk Fauth Yea now I understand. I dint know that I need to use ALT while clicking the column header to invoke the sorting functionality. Thanks for the timely help !

Comment: Only if you don't add the `SingleClickSortConfiguration`. If you add that configuration to your NatTable, sorting also works with a single click. I tested that in the mentioned example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the NatTable Examples Application

*NatTable Examples -> Tutorial Examples -> Integration -> SortableFilterableColumnGroupExample*

This example shows exactly the requested feature combination. Please notice that this example does not include the `SingleClickSortConfiguration`. This means sorting is only triggered by keeping the ALT key pressed while clicking on the column header. Pressing ALT + SHIFT and click will support up to three levels in sorting.

If you want to sort on a single click, you need to additionally add the `SingleClickSortConfiguration` before calling `NatTable#configure()`.

```
this.natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
```